# What symbolism is incorporated in this illustration for a book by Riccati?

Tags: italy, art, mathematics, enlightenment

The front cover of the book Opere (1761) by Jacopo Riccati, author of the celebrated Riccati equation, has the illustration depicted below. What is the symbolism incorporated in this illustration? (This question was originally posted [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/symbolism-in-illustration-for-a-book-by-riccati).)

[image: cover of Opere by Riccati]

Closeup (click to enlarge further, [source](https://digitalcollections.nypl.org/items/5f788d10-85db-0130-dcb4-58d385a7bbd0)):

[image: closeup of Opere illustration]

Edit (Jan 20, 2017):  These two figures are most likely Ecclesia and Synagoga with science linked to Ecclesia and therefore enlightenment and triumph over those who blind themselves to the truth. See my comments and links to Graham's answer. The monstrance, palm frond, and blindfold can be found in Reuben's tapestry as depicted and described in the links.

Comment: Can you add a brief outline as to what the book is about?

Comment: Well, the scientific instruments and geometric images point to a science teatry. The woman in the center seems to hold a palm from (symbol of martyrdom) and a [monstrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrance), but Google cannot tell of any martyr woman that is represented with a monstrance. A relationship of the woman with science and/or knowledge is to be expected, but the saint patron of science is Saint Albert Magno.

Comment: I don't know what the book is about. I'm only familiar wiith his work on the Ricatti equation, which is very important in understanding solion solutions to the KdV, being central to the Lie algebra and associated combinatorics behind such solutions.

Comment: What are the drawings on the pages?

Comment: Btw, I don't believe in gods, demons, ghosts, eternal souls, ..., any supernatural spirits, even luck, so none of the interpretations here related to such reflect my personal views.

Comment: The book is the first of the four volumes of the posthumous complete collection of Riccati’s works, mainly devoted to Physics, Mathematics, especially Analysis and ODE’s. The last volume has his biography, then writings on Metaphysics, Philosophy, and Religion, and his literary production; poetry, mainly sonnets, and a tragedy (“Il Baldassarre”).

Answer (score 4):

[Jacopo Riccati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacopo_Riccati) was an Italian mathematician and jurist from Venice. He is best known for having studied the equation [(Riccati equation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) which bears his name.

As you mentioned in your question, Riccati was educated by the Jesuits. His son [Vincenzo Ricca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenzo_Riccati) actually became a [Jesuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Jesus). It would be safe to say that Riccati had close ties to this Religious Order most his life and was undoubtedly a faithful Catholic.

That taken into consideration, there are several different things to be noted about the cover illustration of the book.

First of all Riccati was a [mathematician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematician) and one can notice objects in the lower left hand corner that suggest he was indeed well educated.

In the middle is A woman holding a object that is emitting rays of light and in the other a branch of some sort. This particular woman, is probably a martyr (and one whom Riccati had a particular devotion to). The branch in her left hand looks like a [palm branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_branch_(symbol)) a Christian symbol of martyrdom. In her right hand, she is holding up what appears to be an artist rendition of a [monstrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrance).It Could be note here that Jesuits make there solemn profession in before the Blessed Sacrament while in a monstrance. It is also the symbol of the Jesuit Order.

[image: Symbolism of Jesuits]

[Symbolism of Jesuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Jesus)

The woman in the lower right quadrant may be a sinner or someone who simply does not share in Riccati's faith.

As a final piece to this, I am going to say that this image shows us that Riccati was illuminated in his studies and achievemenst with the help of his devotion to this particular Saint and Martyr, as well as the [Blessed Sacrament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blessed_Sacrament).

Who this Saint is remains unclear. It may possibly be St Clare of Assisi who is often pictured holding a monstrance.

> In art, Clare is often shown carrying a monstrance or pyx, in commemoration of the occasion when she warded away the soldiers of Frederick II at the gates of her convent by displaying the Blessed Sacrament and kneeling in prayer. [Saint Clare of Assisi (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clare_of_Assisi)

Another possible candidate for the person holding the monstrance could be [Saint Odile of Alsace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odile_of_Alsace), who is often depicted holding a monstrance. She is considered one of the **Patron Saints of good eyesight**.

[image: Saint Odile in Avolsheim, Alsac]

[Saint Odile in Avolsheim, Alsace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odile_of_Alsace)

Comment: Fascinating. Aren't those a pair of eyeglasses on a book on the ground in the lower left?

Comment: @TomCopeland I believe you are correct! They look like eyeglasses to me.

Comment: Or, three apples/oranges/spheres/a trinity? Wish someone could track down a copy of the book and take a closer look. What is the "atom" model actually?

Comment: @Tom Copeland Look up [Armillary sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armillary_sphere)

Comment: I believe the "cloud" is actually a whirlwind with this interpretation:
Jeremiah 23:19

He is talking about a tornado that He has sent—a violent windstorm. The false prophets have said, "No bad is coming" (verse 17). God says, "Do they ever listen to Me? I've said, 'I'm sending a whirlwind, and it's going to fall on the heads of the wicked.' How dare they say that everything is going to be okay!"

Richard T. Ritenbaugh

Comment: The branch held by the prone figure may be related to John 15:6--If a person does not dwell in Me, he is thrown out like a [broken-off] branch, and withers ... .

Comment: See also this panel of Reuben's tapestry http://www.getty.edu/foundation/initiatives/current/panelpaintings/panel_paintings_rubens.html and note the blindfolded figure who could be interpreted as Synagoga, so the blindfold represents a refusal to see the truth http://books.google.com/books?id=PmgcggIXlX8C&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=jesuits+blindfold+symbolism+art&source=bl&ots=G12L7AJdh2&sig=FWcmm8viUnBQqmAas0Qo5dIYEhc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYorDXo8_RAhWhq1QKHVDuCLIQ6AEIJTAE#v=onepage&q=jesuits%20blindfold%20symbolism%20art&f=false

Comment: The last link is to pg. 219 of Tapestry in the Baroque: Threads of Splendor--a discussion of Reuben's tapestry The Triumph of the Eucharist.

Comment: In light of my comment on the cut branch which symbolizes in the Bible those pruned from the ivy (above the prone figure?), representing Christ, which/who don't bear fruit because they don't accept Christ , the "eyeglasses" could very well be fruit with the implication that the sciences as well as faith bear fruit. That would also explain what looks suspiciuosly like a pineapple in the lower left.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_branch_(symbol)

Comment: https://www.reference.com/world-view/pineapple-symbolize-spiritually-8acaa4e923b28cf5

Comment: Don't forget the symbolism behind the right side (dexter) and the left side (sinister) in religious themes that are also reflected in this image. (Also, there is much fruit in swags in the Reubens tapestry.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is clear that the picture shows: "Science and knowledge is light, while ignorance is darkness", a typical symbolism of the Enlightenment period.
(Unlike Ken Graham, I see nothing related to religion in this picture, just the opposite).

Comment: Certainly an enlightenment motif.

Comment: Agree, my guess is that it is Aurora bringing the Dawn on her cloud chariot.

Comment: This is clearly a mix of the secular and non-secular. You could no more convey symbolism in the Enlightenment without reference to religion (pagan or otherwise) than you can now without reference to pop culture (still infused with the archetypes J. Campbell enthusiastically spoke of).

Comment: @Tom Copeland: what is the "non-secular" part of the mix?

Comment: A.E.,  just read the other contriibutions here including the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Following the leads in the wonderful responses of the contributors here, I believe the following interpretations of the symbolism in this picture are probably correct.

These two figures are most likely [Ecclesia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesia_and_Synagoga) (sitting) and Synagoga (prone) with science linked to Ecclesia and therefore enlightenment and triumph over those who blind themselves to the truth.  A [monstrance](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrance), palm frond, a blindfolded figure, and fruit --all depicted in this picture--can be found in Reuben's tapestry [The Triumph of the Eucharist](http://www.getty.edu/foundation/initiatives/current/panelpaintings/panel_paintings_rubens.html), discussed in [Tapestry of the Baroque: Threads of Splendor](http://books.google.com/books?id=PmgcggIXlX8C&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=jesuits%20blindfold%20symbolism%20art&source=bl&ots=G12L7AJdh2&sig=FWcmm8viUnBQqmAas0Qo5dIYEhc&hl=en&sa=X#v=onepage&q=jesuits%20blindfold%20symbolism%20art&f=false) on pg. 219.

Each figure and item is symbolic:

I believe the "cloud" is actually a whirlwind (the foot of God) related to the passage in the Bible Jeremiah 23:19 as discussed by [Ritenbaugh](http://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Topical.show/RTD/CGG/ID/12923/Violent-Windstorm.htm) : He is talking about a tornado that He has sent—a violent windstorm. The false prophets have said, "No bad is coming" (verse 17). God says, "Do they ever listen to Me? I've said, 'I'm sending a whirlwind, and it's going to fall on the heads of the wicked.' How dare they say that everything is going to be okay!"

The palm branch in Ecclesia's hand is a symbol of victory as explained in this [Wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palm_branch_(symbol)).

The branch in Synagoga's hand most likely represents a pruned branch of ivy (ivy is depicted just above Synagoga), related to John 15:6:  "If a person does not dwell in Me, he is thrown out like a [broken-off] branch, and withers ... . " The cut branch symbolizes in the Bible those pruned from the ivy, representing Christ, who don't bear fruit because they don't accept Christ and are therefore cut or broken off the ivy.

The three objects on a book on the ground could very well be fruit with the implication that the sciences as well as faith bear fruit. That would also explain what looks suspiciuosly like a pineapple in the lower left. The symbolism behind pineapples is explained [here](http://www.reference.com/world-view/pineapple-symbolize-spiritually-8acaa4e923b28cf5).

And, don't forget the symbolism behind the right side ([dexter](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_of_God)) and the left side (sinister) in religious themes that are also reflected in this image.

The seashell(s?) in the lower left corner might be associated to St. James, pilgrimage, and the light showing the way (read the section on the Enlightenment Era in the Wiki on [The Way of St. James](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camino_de_Santiago)). Riccati's first name Jacopo is derived from the Latin Iacōbus as is James.

Comment: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_cockle_shell_symbolize_for_Saint_James

Answer (score 0):

I found very interesting to learn the source and the original meanings of Riccati’s Opere’s front-page. I think we should not, however, infer that the author meant to take the signified as well, together with the signifier.

Every aspect of our culture is deeply rooted in Judaism and in Christianity, and art is no exception. Note that for centuries “art” was mainly “holy art”. So, if in the XVIII century you are publishing a scientific work, and you are looking for a good metaphor or for a symbol, say, to represent the Enlightenment idea of “Light of knowledge triumphing over the darkness of ignorance”, you are likely to find good material or inspiration in the rich Christian art and iconography from previous centuries, that of course abounds of images of “X triumphing over Y”. The metaphor of “light vs darkness” itself is taken from the religious tradition, starting with the book of Genesis (Gen,1, 1-5), where it is used with other meanings.
For instance, even the front-pages of (atheist) Diderot’s Encyclopaedia show religious images, or of clear religious source:

[Wikipedia: Encyclopédie ou dictionnaire raisonné des sciences, des arts et des métiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclop%C3%A9die#/media/File:Encyclopedie_de_D%27Alembert_et_Diderot_-_Premiere_Page_-_ENC_1-NA5.jpg)

Taking an image from an old well established tradition does not imply keeping its symbolism: you are likely to choose an image because it is beautiful and fits nicely your needs (and yes, because it shows you are an educated person).

Comment: To whom asked for details: you are welcome, what material would you like to have references about? Most claims are basic facts, and in any case can be easily found online. “Medieval art is mostly holy art”: I have no statistics, but I think everybody agrees on this, and it can be checked by checking the content of any book or museum on the subject.